# How to connect Sqlite database with R Studio?

Tags: r, sqlite, rsqlite

I'm pretty new to working with sqlite databases in R.

> There is an error while installing SQLite

install.packages("RSQLite")

and cannot open URL 'http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/src/contrib/PACKAGES.rds': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'

Error in library(SQLite) : there is no package called ‘SQLite’

Comment: `install.packages("RSQLite", repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org")`?

Comment: Then missing `R` (pun intended?) in `library(RSQLite)`?

Answer (score 0):

The "cannot open URL" message by R is misleading and seems completely harmless. However, the package name in the `library()` call must always match the name of the package you are installing:

```
install.packages("somepackage")
library(somepackage)
# or
library("somepackage")
```